# Can the littlebits arduino make a web request?

Tags: arduino

I have an arduino kit and I want to connect it to IFTTT.com

I know that using the littleBits Cloud is very easy but I don't have it. It is for a scientific purpose and I don't have the time to order an other kit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Arduino from littleBits doesn't have a  network access.

I don't know a lot about your projet but if you use a computer coupled with the Arduino, you can easily write an interface and a server in order to connect to IFTTT.